Automatic countdown powerpoint
I made an countdown in PowerPoint across multiple Slides using this code :
Global time As Date

Sub countdown()

time = Now()
time = DateAdd("n", 10, time)

Do Until time < Now()

DoEvents
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("countdown").TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "nn:ss")
Loop

End Sub

The countdown is on the slide 2 to 5 and i would like that it starts automatically when the slide 2 appears.
Can someone help me?
Thanks
I don't know a lot about vba so i try to find a solution on internet but...
